# Automatically re-spawn a ruby script from within node.js when it fails

Tags: ruby, node.js

I have a Node.js app which when started spawns a Ruby script to connect to a streaming data service and captures the output via STDOUT which is then served to the client via websocket.

Every now and again the Ruby script will fail (normally due to a disconnect from the far end) and while the Node script will carry on running its obviously not aware the spawned Ruby script has died.

Is there any way I can automate recovery of the spawned Ruby script from within Node or Ruby where I don't have to restart the entire Node instance (thus not booting the clients off) and the script will re-spawn attached to the correct instance of Node?

The script is spawned using the following;

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var tail = cp.spawn('/var/www/html/mapper/test/feed1-db.rb');

tail.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
#<more stuff here where data is split and emitted from the socket>#
```

Comment: How are you spawning processes currently? Any code snippets you can provide would be very helpful in getting you a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally had more time to look into this and have decided that it's probably a *very bad* idea to be automatically re-spawning failed scripts! (More on that later)

I have found that I can catch both error's and exit's of the child process by using the following;

```
tail.on('exit', function (code) {
 console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

Which will give me the exit code of the child script.

I also found out that I can catch any other errors using;

```
tail.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.error(`child stderr:\n${data}`);
});
```

Both of these output there error to the console meaning you can still back-trace any issues. I've also expanded the code for the error detection to output a failure notice to connected clients on the web socket.

Now on to why I decided that to auto re-spawn the script was a bad idea...
Up to now most of my underlying issues where caused up stream where I may get some invalid data which would choke my script (I know I should handle that else where but I'm kinda new to this!) or fat fingered problems caused by me!

Without lots of work if the script died due to some invalid data from upstream it would simply try and reconnect to consume the same bad data over and over again till the script got blocked from continuously connecting then disconnecting from the messaging server.

If it was something caused by a fat fingered moment like a bad variable name which isn't often called then I'd have the same problem as above but it could end up bringing down the local server running this script rather then the messaging server. Either way neither of those outcomes are a good way to go!

Unless you are catching very specific exit codes or failures which you know are not 'damaging' then I wouldn't go down this route. The two code blocks above at least allow me to catch the exit/error and notify someone about it so they can intervene and see what triggered it. It also means my on-line users are aware of a background failure where they might see data that appears to be valid, but is actually not updating.

Hopefully this insight helps someone else.